# STM32F4, strange behavior between an IRQ Handler and a function with shared variables

Tags: stm32, stm32f4, irq, isr

I am facing with a weird behavior in my program. For the context, I am programming a STM32F469 microcontroller. The IDE used is SW4STM32 (with Eclipse Neon version (4.6.3)).

To go straight to the point, here is what I have :

```
void foo(void){
    while(1){
        if(var.x == 1){
            var.x = 0;
            var.y = 1;

            // Some irrelevant calculus

            var.y = 0;
        }
    }
```

The `foo()` function doesn't have anything specific. It works, among other irrelevant things here, with a global variable (struct) `var`.

```
void interruption(void){
    if(var.x == 0 && var.y == 0){
        // Some irrelevant calculus
        var.x = 1;
    }
}
```

As its name states, the `interruption()` function is an ISR (Interruption Service Routine). The interruption associated to this ISR is raised approximately every 16ms. It works with the same global variable (struct) `var`.

Finally, here is my `main`:

```
int main(void)
{
    myStruct var;
    var.x = 0;
    var.y = 0;

    // Some initialization (the ISR for example)

    foo();
}
```

Ok so what I don't understand is that the whole process only works if there is "something" between the `while` loop and the `if` condition, for example : a delay or the switch of a pin state in the `foo()` function :

```
 void foo(void){
    **Place something here to make the process work, a 1ms delay for example**
    while(1){
        if(var.x == 1){
            var.x = 0;
            var.y = 1;

            // Some irrelevant calculus

            var.y = 0;
        }
    }
```

Just to be specific : when it doesn't work, it means that neither my program goes through the `if` condition in the ISR nor the `if` condition in the `foo()` function. When it does work, the program goes through both of them (`if` condition).

The fact that both of the `if` condition are false means that :

1. `var.x == 0`
2. `var.y == 1`
3. Both of these values are true **outside** the `if` condition. The thing is, and that's where something is wrong here, normally these values are encountered only in the `if` condition of the `foo()` function. And if I am in this state, `var.y` **has** to be equal to `0`at the end of this condition.

`var` is currently used nowhere else.

So, my question is, do you have any explaination about this phenomenom ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably seeing register caching in action.  Make sure that your globals are declared as `volatile` (see https://barrgroup.com/Embedded-Systems/How-To/C-Volatile-Keyword).  Basically, the generated code doesn't think that `var.x` can change outside of the current function.  The `volatile` keyword tells the code generator that it should assume that the value is modified by an asynchronous action (ISR, signal handler, other thread, etc).

Oh, and I'm assuming that the target language is C or C++ since the language defines the `volatile` keyword.

Comment: I have never completely understood how, why and when `volatile` keyword should be used (as your article states btw). Now I know. It solved the problem. Thanks !

Comment: @D.Shawley it is not sufficient in your case !!! It has to be atomic as well. volatile does not anything else only assures loads and stores of the object, but not the atomicity.  He checks the value and takes the action for the value which might be meanwhile changed (between load / modify / store).